# Qt menus disappear in Unity

Tags: unity, menu, qt

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 and updated the whole system last week. (just to clarify that I'm up to date)

When I'm using qt applications like QtCreator, Opera, Dolphin and so on, their context menus start to disappear after some time. So I'm not able to see the menus when right-clicking stuff. This can take a bunch minutes and restarting those apps sometimes fixes it (for some time again). Seems like last week's update doesn't allow me to fix stuff by restarting the apps anymore.

Does anyone experience the same bug ?

(It works normal in xfce and kde)

Comment: I have experienced the same odd thing with qt creator- it just disappears from the task menu while its open... it's still there but I have to look for the window manually since it disappears from alt tab too... if you have found a solution please save me from that curse too!

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same problems with qt applications in Unity (Unity 2D is not affected). There is an active bug report but no solution so far:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/929712

My temporary solution is indeed to use Unity 2D